# @SpringBootTest resulting in 'No tests found for given includes'

Tags: java, spring, unit-testing, spring-boot, junit

I have simple unit test which starts my app and tests that certain services have been instantiated. Kind of just a sanity check.

However, these tests are not being run in my full test suite, and when run individually i get the error `No tests found for given includes: [com.example.AppTest](filter.includeTestsMatching)`

This is my unit test

```
import com.sblukcic.cli.flags.CLIParser;
import org.junit.Rule;
import org.junit.jupiter.api.BeforeAll;
import org.junit.jupiter.api.Test;
import org.junit.jupiter.api.extension.ExtendWith;
import org.junit.rules.TemporaryFolder;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.boot.test.context.SpringBootTest;
import org.springframework.context.ApplicationContext;
import org.springframework.test.context.junit.jupiter.SpringExtension;

import java.io.BufferedWriter;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileWriter;
import java.io.IOException;

import static org.assertj.core.api.AssertionsForClassTypes.assertThat;
import static org.junit.Assert.fail;

@ExtendWith(SpringExtension.class)
@SpringBootTest
public class AppTest {

    @Autowired
    private ApplicationContext context;

    @Autowired
    private CLIParser parser;

    @Rule
    public static TemporaryFolder folder = new TemporaryFolder();

    private static File nonEmptyFile;

    @BeforeAll
    public static void setUp() throws Exception {
        folder.create();
        nonEmptyFile = folder.newFile("myNextFile.txt");

        try(BufferedWriter br = new BufferedWriter(new FileWriter(nonEmptyFile))){
            br.write("I AM NOT EMPTY!");
            br.flush();
        }catch (IOException ioe){
            fail();
        }
    }

    @Test
    public void givenAppStarted_whenLoaded_checkContextLoaded() {
        assertThat(context).isNotNull();
    }

    @Test
    public void whenAppStarted_checkParserLoadedCorrectly() {
        assertThat(parser).isNotNull();
    }

}
```

Any ideas, thanks in advance.

Edit: I've just run the test with the --debug option, and it shows this just before the test fails

```
11:06:58.322 [QUIET] [system.out] </event></ijLog>
11:06:58.322 [DEBUG] [TestEventLogger]     [11:06:58] [32m[INFO][m Starting AppTest on equipment with PID 22040 (started by sam in /home/sam/IdeaProjects/SBL Xsam Kit)
11:06:58.325 [QUIET] [system.out] 
11:06:58.325 [QUIET] [system.out] </event></ijLog>
11:06:58.325 [DEBUG] [TestEventLogger]     [11:06:58] [32m[INFO][m No active profile set, falling back to default profiles: default
11:06:58.944 [LIFECYCLE] [org.gradle.process.internal.health.memory.MemoryManager] 
11:06:58.944 [DEBUG] [org.gradle.process.internal.health.memory.MemoryManager] Emitting OS memory status event {Total: 67473440768, Free: 55896666112}
11:06:58.944 [DEBUG] [org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.health.LowMemoryDaemonExpirationStrategy] Received memory status update: {Total: 67473440768, Free: 55896666112}
11:06:58.944 [DEBUG] [org.gradle.process.internal.health.memory.MemoryManager] Emitting JVM memory status event {Maximum: 1016594432, Committed: 1009778688}
11:06:59.605 [DEBUG] [org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.Daemon] DaemonExpirationPeriodicCheck running
11:06:59.605 [DEBUG] [org.gradle.cache.internal.DefaultFileLockManager] Waiting to acquire shared lock on daemon addresses registry.
11:06:59.605 [DEBUG] [org.gradle.cache.internal.DefaultFileLockManager] Lock acquired on daemon addresses registry.
11:06:59.605 [DEBUG] [org.gradle.cache.internal.DefaultFileLockManager] Releasing lock on daemon addresses registry.
11:06:59.605 [DEBUG] [org.gradle.cache.internal.DefaultFileLockManager] Waiting to acquire shared lock on daemon addresses registry.
11:06:59.606 [DEBUG] [org.gradle.cache.internal.DefaultFileLockManager] Lock acquired on daemon addresses registry.
11:06:59.606 [DEBUG] [org.gradle.cache.internal.DefaultFileLockManager] Releasing lock on daemon addresses registry.
11:06:59.930 [DEBUG] [org.gradle.internal.remote.internal.inet.SocketConnection] Discarding EOFException: java.io.EOFException
11:06:59.938 [DEBUG] [org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.SynchronizedDispatchConnection] thread 6911: dispatching class org.gradle.launcher.daemon.protocol.BuildEvent
11:06:59.939 [DEBUG] [org.gradle.cache.internal.btree.BTreePersistentIndexedCache] Opening cache fileHashes.bin (/home/sam/IdeaProjects/SBL Xsam Kit/.gradle/4.8/fileHashes/fileHashes.bin)
11:06:59.940 [DEBUG] [org.gradle.cache.internal.btree.BTreePersistentIndexedCache] Opening cache taskHistory.bin (/home/sam/IdeaProjects/SBL Xsam Kit/.gradle/4.8/taskHistory/taskHistory.bin)
11:06:58.299 [LIFECYCLE] [org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor] 
11:06:58.299 [LIFECYCLE] [org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor] > Task :test FAILED
11:06:59.464 [QUIET] [system.out] 
11:06:59.465 [QUIET] [system.out] </event></ijLog>
11:06:59.465 [DEBUG] [TestEventLogger]     [11:06:59] [32m[INFO][m Started AppTest in 1.547 seconds (JVM running for 4.207)
11:06:59.931 [DEBUG] [org.gradle.process.internal.DefaultExecHandle] Changing state to: SUCCEEDED
```

Edit2: Gradle setup

```
plugins {
    id 'java'
    id 'jacoco'
}

//gradle wrapper --gradle-version 4.10.3

group 'com.sblukcic'
version '1.0-SNAPSHOT'

sourceCompatibility = 1.8

repositories {
    mavenCentral()
    maven { url 'https://jitpack.io' }
}

dependencies {
    // https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.mockito/mockito-core
    testCompile group: 'org.mockito', name: 'mockito-core', version: '2.18.3'

    // https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.springframework.boot/spring-boot-starter-test
    testCompile (group: 'org.springframework.boot', name: 'spring-boot-starter-test', version: '2.1.4.RELEASE'){
        exclude group: 'org.springframework.boot', module: 'spring-boot-starter-logging'
    }

    // https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.junit.jupiter/junit-jupiter-api
    testCompile group: 'org.junit.jupiter', name: 'junit-jupiter-api', version: '5.3.2'

    // https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.junit.jupiter/junit-jupiter-params
    testCompile group: 'org.junit.jupiter', name: 'junit-jupiter-params', version: '5.3.2'

    testRuntime(
            'org.junit.jupiter:junit-jupiter-engine:5.1.0',
            'org.junit.vintage:junit-vintage-engine:5.1.0',
            'org.junit.platform:junit-platform-launcher:1.1.0',
            'org.junit.platform:junit-platform-runner:1.1.0'
    )

    // https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.springframework.boot/spring-boot-starter
    compile (group: 'org.springframework.boot', name: 'spring-boot-starter', version: '2.1.4.RELEASE') {
        exclude group: 'org.springframework.boot', module: 'spring-boot-starter-logging'
    }

    // https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.springframework.boot/spring-boot-starter-log4j2
    compile group: 'org.springframework.boot', name: 'spring-boot-starter-log4j2', version: '2.1.4.RELEASE'

    // https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.projectlombok/lombok
    compileOnly group: 'org.projectlombok', name: 'lombok', version: '1.18.6'

    // https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/commons-chain/commons-chain
    compile group: 'commons-chain', name: 'commons-chain', version: '1.2'

    // https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.beust/jcommander
    compile group: 'com.beust', name: 'jcommander', version: '1.72'


    // https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.jacoco/org.jacoco.core
    compile group: 'org.jacoco', name: 'org.jacoco.core', version: '0.8.3'

    //in house code.
    compile 'com.gitlab.SBLUKcic:xsam-core:1.42'
    compile 'com.gitlab.SBLUKcic:apu-convert:1.1'
}

jacoco {
    toolVersion = "0.8.2"
    reportsDir = file("$buildDir/customJacocoReportDir")

}

jacocoTestReport {
    reports {
        xml.enabled false
        csv.enabled false
        html.destination file("${buildDir}/jacocoHtml")
    }
}

jacocoTestCoverageVerification{
    violationRules{
        rule{
            limit{
                minimum = 0.7
            }
        }
    }
}


test{

    useJUnitPlatform {
        includeEngines 'junit-jupiter', 'junit-vintage'
    }

    maxHeapSize = '2G'

    failFast = true

    finalizedBy jacocoTestReport

}
```

Comment: Please provide full gradle/maven definition files.

Comment: @Sheinbergon I've added my build.gradle file for you

Comment: Lacking the rest of your project layout - did you try setting `@ComponentScan` or `@ContextConfiguration` annotations?

Comment: @Sheinbergon turns out it was an issue with beans not being present - although I thought that `@SpringBootApplication` handled that. I had to add a mixture of `@MockBean` and `@SpringBootTest(classes = {..})` to get it to work. It's strange that it comes up as an `EOFException` in the logs

Comment: @sam I'm facing the same issue. How did you manage to diagnose the offending spring context errror ? Did you find a way to get verbose logs for the springboot context loading ? I tried naive logback debug configuration for loggers org.springframework.boot.test and org.springframework.test.context.junit.jupiter without

Comment: I was with a similar issue and it was solved with `@SpringBootTest(classes = MyMainClass.class)` instead simply `@SpringBootTest`