# How to troubleshoot @SpringBootTest leading to "No tests found for given includes"?

Tags: gradle, intellij-idea, junit5, spring-boot-test

I'm working on a SpringBoot test which fails to launch any test case apparently as a side effect of the springboot context being modified with additional beans.

Initially, the test cases from [CreateServiceKeyBindingComponentTest](https://github.com/orange-cloudfoundry/osb-cmdb-spike/blob/5ca777827b6a2ae7bb7468f9e09fbdc88bba2e5c/spring-cloud-app-broker-integration-tests/src/test/java/org.springframework.cloud.appbroker/integration/CreateServiceKeyBindingComponentTest.java#L46) are detected properly by idea 2019.3/gradle 6.0.1/junit 5.5.2/springboot 2.2.4, and properly execute.

With some additional beans loaded in the context, see [diff](https://github.com/orange-cloudfoundry/osb-cmdb-spike/commit/33ead9bdfcfb2a873164117647924f356a9477d1#diff-3be56f55f7e43f84ad994213dc6c0466) from [commit 33ead9](https://github.com/orange-cloudfoundry/osb-cmdb-spike/commit/33ead9bdfcfb2a873164117647924f356a9477d1), the test suprisingly fails with the following message, and no detected test case

```
> Task :spring-cloud-app-broker-integration-tests:testClasses UP-TO-DATE
> Task :spring-cloud-app-broker-integration-tests:test FAILED
Test result: SUCCESS
Test summary: 0 tests, 0 succeeded, 0 failed, 0 skipped
FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.
* What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':spring-cloud-app-broker-integration-tests:test'.
> No tests found for given includes: [org.springframework.cloud.appbroker.integration.CreateServiceKeyBindingComponentTest](filter.includeTestsMatching)
```

**What troubleshooting steps can be used in gradle/junit/springboot-context  to fix such unexpected "No tests found" symptom ?**

This looks similar to [@SpringBootTest resulting in 'No tests found for given includes'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56110026/springboottest-resulting-in-no-tests-found-for-given-includes) which did not provide diagnostics

I tried the following approaches without luck

0- intellij stop and checking no gradle daemon was still running, before restarting intellij

1- specifying `--debug` in gradle argument to get debug output did not provide useful logs

```
2020-03-11T18:07:07.042+0100 [DEBUG] [TestEventLogger] Gradle Test Run :spring-cloud-app-broker-integration-tests:test STARTED
2020-03-11T18:07:07.052+0100 [QUIET] [system.out] 
2020-03-11T18:07:07.052+0100 [QUIET] [system.out] Test result: SUCCESS
2020-03-11T18:07:07.052+0100 [QUIET] [system.out] Test summary: 0 tests, 0 succeeded, 0 failed, 0 skipped
2020-03-11T18:07:07.052+0100 [QUIET] [system.out] 
2020-03-11T18:07:07.053+0100 [QUIET] [system.out] </event></ijLog>
2020-03-11T18:07:07.053+0100 [DEBUG] [TestEventLogger] 
2020-03-11T18:07:07.053+0100 [DEBUG] [TestEventLogger] Gradle Test Run :spring-cloud-app-broker-integration-tests:test PASSED
```

2- trying to naively display springboot verbose log using logback did not produce further logs (see [full diff](https://github.com/spring-cloud/spring-cloud-app-broker/commit/5ca777827b6a2ae7bb7468f9e09fbdc88bba2e5c#diff-68de24eb9f8f8b0ffba9235296af049f))

```
    <logger name="org.springframework.test.context.junit.jupiter" level="debug" />
    <logger name="org.springframework.boot.test" level="debug" />
```

3- trying to run the test with intellij instead of gradle leads to no further output (see related [Intelij 2019.1 update breaks JUnit tests](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55405441/intelij-2019-1-update-breaks-junit-tests))

```
java ... com.intellij.rt.execution.application.AppMainV2 com.intellij.rt.junit.JUnitStarter -ideVersion5 -junit5 org.springframework.cloud.appbroker.integration.CreateServiceKeyBindingComponentTest
##teamcity[enteredTheMatrix]
##teamcity[treeEnded]
```

Full list of other diagnostics considered in [log file](https://github.com/orange-cloudfoundry/osb-cmdb-spike/blob/service-binding-params/osb-cmdb/TODO.md) along with associated [commits](https://github.com/orange-cloudfoundry/osb-cmdb-spike/commits/service-binding-params)

---

EDIT

The "no tests found..." error suddenly disappeared after being consistently being reproductible by adding/removing the offending beans in the spring context. I'm unable to reproduce it anymore nor to clearly identify what fixed it in my environment :-(

Here are in between steps that I ran even through they seem unrelated and I don't explain how they could have influenced/fixed the issue:

0- the update of springboot/junit/gradle in [commit d9fda3](https://github.com/orange-cloudfoundry/osb-cmdb-spike/commit/d9fda3ee65f33d1481d0e59e9fab318cf7f16307) which would not have properly be reloaded by intellij/gradle daemon

1- passing the `--scan` option to the gradle build (which produces a [build scan](https://guides.gradle.org/creating-build-scans/))

> A build scan is a shareable and centralized record of a build that provides insights into what happened and why.

2- turning on the intellij [Enable Gradle script debugging](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/2019.3/run-debug-gradle.html?utm_campaign=IU&utm_content=2019.3&utm_medium=link&utm_source=product#) option

3- run the gradle build within Idea debugger by hitting "Debug" on the gradle   configuration

4- stopping the gradle daemon with `./gradlew --stop`

Answer (score 0):

Running a `gradle clean` at the top level project finally solved the issue for me (once it reproduced again).

Notes of further unsuccessfull attempts:

- A `gradle clean`at the subproject level (of this multi module project)
- Executing test using intellij runner instead of gradle runner
- Exiting the gradle daemon with `./gradlew -stop`

Answer (score 0):

One common reason why the tests are not found is because the test runner is missing or the wrong version is used.

If you are using *Gradle*, you must have one of the following lines in the `dependencies` block of your `build.gradle`:

- for JUnit 4: `testRuntimeOnly('org.junit.vintage:junit-vintage-engine')`
- for JUnit 5: `testRuntimeOnly('org.junit.jupiter:junit-jupiter-engine')`

Source = [JUnit 5 User Guide - Running Tests](https://junit.org/junit5/docs/snapshot/user-guide/index.html#running-tests)

This does not answer directly the question but might help with troubleshooting the issue.